# My function that is trying to read a csv file and put the data into a 2d array is returning null value

Tags: c++

Sorry, new to c++ and still trying to figure it out. I'm trying to get data from a csv file and put them into a 2dArray. I think I have the loops and string streams working fine, but whenever I try and run it the array returns with null. Is there a specific function to push stringstream into an array or am I missing something entirely?

```
bool readUsers(string fh, string data[ROWS][COLS]) {
  fh = "./data/user_info.csv"; 
  std::ifstream in(fh);

  if (in.is_open()){ 
  std::string line;
  std::string token;
    for(int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++ ){
            std::stringstream lineStream(line);
      for(int j = 0; j < COLS; j++){
          std::getline(lineStream, data[i][j], ',');
          lineStream = data[i][j];
          } 
      }
  }
  else{
    return false;
  }
  }
}
```

The csv file is comma delimited so it looks somewhat like

```
  "Name", "Email", "Job"
  "Name", "Email", "Job"
  "Name", "Email", "Job"
  "Name", "Email", "Job"
```

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: Not sure why you have this: `lineStream = data[i][j];`

Comment: Also, ask yourself: What line in my code actually reads some data from `in`

Comment: There should have been a getline() before `std::stringstream lineStream(line);` to read a line of text into `line`

Comment: Too many issues in the code: (1) you read from lineStream which is initially empty; (2) you separate by comma and forgot about '\n'; (3) C++ will read quote marks (") as part of the string between commas (,), so you won't get want you want. Fix these 3 and after that we could help to find the solution if the help will still be needed.